# how to get the margin from libSVM

Tags: .net, libsvm, svm

I'm using the libSVM for .net.
After running the SVM training i get a vector of alphas.
As i understand, the margin is the minimum distance
between any point and the decision hyperplane.

I'm not sure how to do that using the alphas.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

> Q: How do I get the distance between a point and the hyperplane?
>
> The distance is |decision_value| / |w|. We have |w|^2 = w^Tw = alpha^T Q alpha = 2*(dual_obj + sum alpha_i). Thus in svm.cpp please find the place where we calculate the dual objective value (i.e., the subroutine Solve()) and add a statement to print w^Tw.

[From the `libsvm` FAQ:](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/%7Ecjlin/libsvm/faq.html#f4151)